# React: Can't enter decimal in input element

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-hooks

I am building a tip calculator. I have three variables: **Tip**, **Bill**, and **People**. I want to display the calculated values as I entered the input values. When I tried to enter a decimal inside the **Bill** input, it will not let me. Also, when I click on the **People** input, it will start at 1. So if I entered 2, it will be 12. How to fix this?

```js
import "./styles.css";
import {useState} from 'react'

export default function App() {
const [calc, setCalc] = useState({
  bill: 0,
  tip: 0,
  people: 1,
})
const [error, setError] = useState({
  people: false,
  bill: false
})

// var tipPerPerson = (calc.bill * (1 + (calc.tip/100)))/calc.people;
var tipPerPerson = (calc.bill * (calc.tip/100));
var totalPerPerson = (calc.bill + tipPerPerson)/calc.people;

const handleBillChange = (event) => {
  const input = Number(event.target.value);
  if (!isNaN(input)) {
    setCalc({
      ...calc,
      bill: input
    });
  }
};

const handleTipClick = (event) => {
  const input = Number(event.target.value);
  if (!isNaN(input)) {
    setCalc({
      ...calc,
      tip: input
    });
  }
};

const handlePeoplelChange = (event) => {
  const input = Number(event.target.value);
  if (!isNaN(input) && input > 0) {
    setError({
      ...error,
      people: false
    });
    setCalc({
      ...calc,
      people: input
    });
  }
  else {
    setError({
      ...error,
      people: true
    });
  }
};

const handleResetClick = () =>{
  setCalc({
    ...calc,
    bill: 0,
    people: 1,
    tip: 0
  })
}

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="calculator">
        <div className="calculator__item">
          <label htmlFor="bill" >Bill: </label>
          <input onChange={handleBillChange} placeholder="$0" value={calc.bill} id="bill"  />
        </div>
        <div className="calculator__item tip__buttons">
          <button value={10} onClick={handleTipClick}>10%</button>
          <button value={15} onClick={handleTipClick}>15%</button>
        <button value={20} onClick={handleTipClick}>20%</button>
        </div>
        <div className="calculator__item">
        <label htmlFor="people">Number of People: </label>
          <input onChange={handlePeoplelChange} placeholder="1" value={calc.people} id="people"  />
          {error.people && <p className="invalid">Can't be zero</p>}
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="display">
        <p>
          Tip Amount Per Person: {(tipPerPerson).toFixed(2)}
        </p>
        <p>Total Amount Per Person: {(totalPerPerson).toFixed(2)}</p>
        <button onClick={handleResetClick}>Reset</button>
      </div>
      </div>
  );
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Update your bill input to type number.

```
   <input
        type="number"
        onChange={handleBillChange}
        placeholder="$0"
        value={calc.bill}
        id="bill"
       />

  const handleBillChange = (event) => {
    const input = event.target.value;
    setCalc({
      ...calc,
      bill: input
    });
  };
```

Code Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/eloquent-goldberg-yd6nvf?file=/src/App.js:442-579

Comment: why when you enter something inside the input (the bill input and the number of people input), the initial value is include while typing?

Comment: so, you're saying the default value is 1 but when you enter 2 you want the input field to show 2 and not 12?